# Error in pytest with django response codes

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I am using pytest to test my django rest framework API and am gettin gan error on the following test:

```
def test_client_gets_invalid_when_submitting_invlaid_data(self):
    client = APIClient()
    response = client.post(path="/user/register/", data={})
    assert response.status_code is 400
```

traceback in pytest is as follows:

```
>       assert response.status_code is 400
E       assert 400 is 400
E        +  where 400 = <Response status_code=400, "application/json">.status_code

core\tests\test_views.py:26: AssertionError
```

I dont understand how this error can be happening when 400 is literally equal to 400?

Comment: Try using `==`? - `assert response.status_code is 400`

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the keyword `is` tests for identity in memory, where as `==` tests for value.

So the solution was to simply change from `is` to `==`

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-object-comparison-is-vs/